# MS Excel spot difference in a row, find which column the change is in and print out column header

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

First of all,
Hi and thank you for taking the time to read this. I've been thinking of tangling this problem for a while now and decided now is as good of a time as any. The problem is as follows:

Let's say we have a table of Appointments like the following:

[image: the following]

The Headers refer each to a type of appointment, like dental, mental, physio, etc and expands, in my case, up to 30 columns. How can I efficiently find out which number has changed in a table like that? My actual data set consists of 10k+ rows and about 55 rows in total (but only need to pick-up the changes in only 30 of those columns, all next to each other.)

At first, I thought how about using SUM to add up all the values in the fields and see whether there's been a change, but then there's still the 30 columns to go through and manually pick-up where the changed happened. So, what formula, or combination of formulas, could I use that would spot the difference in a row of fields, then find which column the difference belongs to, and print out the column header in a new column?

P.S. There's Duplicates.

Comment: When you speak about change, do you mean compared to a previous version? How it can be spotted? Based on your memories? Or is there another source?

Comment: Did you mean the number changed manually and you want to mark the number？

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood correctly:

> Compare rows with the same ID and identify those columns where the row
> with the later date is different from the row with the earlier date.

Easiest is to use Power Query.

Here is the code for the advanced editor in Power Query. If you're not sure what to do with it, please read on.

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],

    //make the table tall instead of wide
    Unpivot = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns( Source , {"ID","ApptDate"} , "ApptType" , "Value"),

    //join the table with itself on ID and date < other date
    Crossjoin = Table.AddColumn(
                    Unpivot,
                    "crossjoin",
                    (outer) => Table.SelectRows(
                                    Table.PrefixColumns(Unpivot,"New"),
                                    (inner) =>  outer[ID] = inner[New.ID] and 
                                                outer[ApptType] = inner[New.ApptType] and 
                                                outer[ApptDate] < inner[New.ApptDate] and 
                                                outer[Value] <> inner[New.Value]
                                )
                ),

    //get only those rows where the value has changed
    Changes = Table.SelectRows( Crossjoin , each not Table.IsEmpty([crossjoin])),

    //expand the crossjoin column
    Expand = Table.ExpandTableColumn( Changes , "crossjoin" , {"New.ApptDate","New.Value"})
in
    Expand
```

1. If it's not already, convert your data to a Table. Put your cursor
   anywhere in your range and use Ctrl+T.
2. Use Date>Get Data>From Other Sources>Blank Query:

[image]

The Power Query editor will open.

3. On the home tab, click 'Advanced Editor'. It will look like this:

[image]

4. Remove the code that's there and replace it with the code above
5. Click Done on the Advanced Editor
6. Use Home>Close & Load

The result looks like this:

[image]

There will be one row for each difference in Value where the date in column B has been compared with the date in column E for the appointment type in column C and the ID in column A.